# Why my batch file in windows is not executing continuously?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My batch file is like this.......

D: & cd directory1 & dex2jar classes.dex 
E: & cd directory2 & dex2jar classes.dex 
F: & cd directory3 & dex2jar classes.dex 
E: & cd directory4 & dex2jar classes.dex....... ( many similar lines of code )

Problem in executing this is only first line is getting executed and the cmd closes without executing remaining lines WHY?... How can this be solved?

[NOTE] "dex2jar classes.dex" command converts my classes.dex into executable jar file
Is this command "dex2jar classes.dex" causing the problem?

Thank you

Comment: try `start "" "D: & cd directory1 & dex2jar classes.dex "`

Comment: If you run the batch file from a command prompt, what output do you see? Is it possible that "cd directory2" is failing?

Comment: start is not working @Stephan

Comment: Yse "cd directory2" is working correctly if i run all the commands separately all working but as a batch file it is not working @JimRhodes

Comment: First command working and generates exe jar file and then cmd closes without executing the next line in batch file@JimRhodes

Comment: Can you post your actual batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `&` in every line, if you don't have a good reason.

It currently fails as dex2jar is possible a batch file itself and batch failes has to be called with `CALL`.

So your code could look like

```
cd /D D:\directory1
call dex2jar classes.dex

cd /D E:\directory1
call dex2jar classes.dex

cd /D F:\directory1
call dex2jar classes.dex
```